# Hide entry-header for a specific category

Tags: customization, categories, css

I now you can hide the entry-header using css but what if I want just to hide it for a specific category?

```
<div class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-meta category-meta">
        <div class="cat-links"><a href="https://web.com/category/mycategory/" rel="category tag">Auspiciadores</a></div>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="https://web.com/2020/02/06/entry-two/">My Category</a></h2>        
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <div class="date"><a href="https://web.com/2020/02/06/entry-two/" title="Entry Two">6 february 2020</a> </div> 
        <div class="by-author vcard author"><a href="https://entry-two/author/somebody/">Somebody</a> </div>                                                                
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to aply something like the following css but just for an especific category:

```
.entry-header {
    display:none;
}
```

EDIT:

Can I accomplish this writing in functions.php something like this:

```
function prefix_category_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_category( 'auspiciadores' ) ) {
        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_action( 'get_the_archive_title', 'prefix_category_title' );
```

Comment: if your theme uses `body_class()` and/or `post_class()` you should have specific selectors to use for CSS. Formatting questions are off-topic here in the forum. Please consider asking the developer of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
body.category-uncategorized .entry-header {
    display:none;
}
```

"uncategorized" Should be your category slug. This is for the post category only. If you have a custom registered category then you can check the  element. There you should get your category name.

This is what for WooCommerce category:
[image]

So you should use like this for WooCommerce "accessories" Category:

```
body.term-accessories .entry-header {
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the section that writes the information od the post:

if ( is_category( 'mycategory' ) )
        {
            the_title( '' );
        }
        else 
        {
            the_title( '', '' );
        } 
    ?>
    ', '' ); ?>
    
    
        if ( is_category( 'mycategory' ) )
        {
            //nothing
        }
        else 
        {
            newscard_posted_on();
        } 
    ?>